# How to make executable jar in testng using maven

Tags: maven, testng, maven-plugin, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

Can anyone help me how to make executable jar for testng maven project. My goal is to run the testng executable jar using bat file to run the unit testing

Below is my folder structure

[image]

Appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 simple way, you can create executable jar by clicking right on eclipse follow - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

And create 1 java class which will invoke your testNG xml file and execute using testNG.run().

public class InvokeTestNGJava {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Started!");
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("src"+File.separator+"main"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"stats-comparison.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}
```

}

And java class will run using - java -classpath yourjar.jar youpackage.InvokeTestNGJava. It simple invoke testng xml and run it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the maven plugin to run the testNG with mvn test

```
<build>
        <!-- Source directory configuration -->
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If you really want an executable jar (WHICH I DON'T THINK YOU DO) you need the shade plugin:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>tester</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    ....
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>com.greg.Application</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi Essex, I followed your way and go the error "Error: Could not find or load main class". Also we use the testng.xml in the main method. How do we give reference when the testng.xml present outside the application? Also let me know what goal to use.